# I want to display lines of text on a Webpage from a .txt file, and have it update every day

Tags: php, css, text, html

I have a .txt file that has lines of text (bible verses) that include the date. I want to be able to display the text on our website, so that it shows the correct reading for that day and updates every day. Here is an example of the text:

> Monday, December 28 — Psalm 148:1–6 Zechariah 10,11; Revelation
>   20:1–10
>
> The Lord our God we will serve, and him we will obey. Joshua 24:24
>
> Be steadfast, immovable, always excelling in the work of the Lord,
>   because you know that in the Lord your labor is not in vain. 1
>   Corinthians 15:58
>
> Tireless Creator, often we succumb to post-celebration doldrums. We
>   lose our enthusiasm for service and witness. Help us remember that
>   even in the dullness of daily routine we can share your grace.
>   Rekindle the coals of our hearts with the fire of your love. Amen.
>
> Tuesday, December 29 — Psalm 148:7–14 Zechariah 12–13:6; Revelation
>   20:11–21:8
>
> God gives wisdom to the wise and knowledge to those who have
>   understanding. Daniel 2:21
>
> Do not be foolish, but understand what the will of the Lord is.
>   Ephesians 5:17
>
> It is difficult to discern your will, God of Wisdom. The Scriptures
>   inform us, but interpretations can be controversial, even adversarial.
>   Forgive our allowance of such disagreements to obstruct the work of
>   your Spirit in us. Show us how to live the way, the truth, and the
>   life of sacrificial love. Amen.

Any help you could offer would be greatly appreciated - I'm a code hobbyist, so it's probably best to treat me as a novice, if that helps. Thank you!

this is the kind of php code I've been playing with:

```
 <?php  // script.php


  $searchfor = $_GET['january'];

         $file = '2016 Daily Texts no hymns mac.txt';

   $contents = file_get_contents($file);
     $pattern = preg_quote($searchfor, '/');
    $pattern = "/$pattern/m";

     if(preg_match_all($pattern, $contents, $matches)){
            echo "Found matches:<br />";
       echo implode("<br />", $matches[0]);
      }
       else{
             echo "No matches found";
        fclose ($file); 
         }
       ?>
```

Comment: Post some code that you've trying to do.

Comment: Any chance you can store these versus in XML or other data source?  Especially when considering how big the text-file can be, scanning through it with no markers for the date can require a lot of resources.

It needs to have some formatting to it: <Entry><Month>December</Month><Day>30</Day><Verse>Bible Verse Here</Verse></Entry>

This will also leave out all of the logic to try and figure out where the verse ends.

Comment: I could easily do that. What about an excel file?

Answer (score 0):

So long as the date format is always consistent throughout the text

**eg.** *Monday, December 28*

your webpage will be able to extract a new verse for each day without any issue:

```
<?php

$today = date('l, F j');
$today_as_unix_timestamp = strtotime($today);
$tomorrow_as_unix_timestamp = ($today_as_unix_timestamp + (60 * 60 * 24));
$tomorrow = date('l, F j',$tomorrow_as_unix_timestamp);

$verses = file_get_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/2016_Daily_Texts_no_hymns_mac.txt');
$start = (strpos($verses,$today) + strlen($today));
$end = (strpos($verses,$tomorrow));

$verse_for_today = substr($verses,$start,($end - $start));

echo '<p>'.$verse_for_today.'</p>';

?>
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use php to read the text file

```
<body>
<pre>
    <?php
    $myfile = fopen("text.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
    echo fread($myfile,filesize("text.txt"));
    fclose($myfile);
    ?>
</pre>
```

Comment: This doesn't only show an item for the current date